# Meteor: Installation on Windows 10 (64 Bit)?

Tags: windows, meteor, installation

I've been trying to install Meteor on my Windows 10 PC for a while now without success. Not sure what to do at this point so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I've opened Command Prompt as an Aministrator, wrote 'meteor create myApp' on my Desktop and have recieved the following error:

```
C:\Users\L\Desktop>meteor create myapp
C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;
      ^

Error: No metadata files found for isopack at: /C/Users/L/AppData/Local/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/1.3.3
    at Isopack._loadUnibuildsFromPath (C:\tools\isobuild\isopack.js:904:13)
    at _.each (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:521:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\L\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.0\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at buildmessage.enterJob (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:520:13)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:515:22
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at Object.download (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:427:20)
    at C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:600:22
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at exports.Tropohouse.downloadPackagesMissingFromMap (C:\tools\packaging\tropohouse.js:597:20)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:814:25
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:813:20
    at C:\tools\packaging\catalog\catalog.js:100:5
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Object.catalog.runAndRetryWithRefreshIfHelpful (C:\tools\packaging\catalog\catalog.js:99:31)
    at ProjectContext._downloadMissingPackages (C:\tools\project-context.js:812:13)
    at C:\tools\project-context.js:285:9
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:359:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:352:34
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:350:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.enterJob (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:324:26)
    at ProjectContext._completeStagesThrough (C:\tools\project-context.js:275:18)
    at Profile.run (C:\tools\project-context.js:267:12)
    at Function.run (C:\tools\tool-env\profile.js:490:12)
    at ProjectContext.prepareProjectForBuild (C:\tools\project-context.js:266:13)
    at C:\tools\cli\commands.js:793:20
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
    at exports.EnvironmentVariable.withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at Object.main.captureAndExit (C:\tools\cli\main.js:274:29)
    at Command.func (C:\tools\cli\commands.js:767:8)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1522:15
```

What must I do?

Regards

Comment: I recommend linux to use meteor

Comment: Just so you don't feel forced to go on linux, it works perfectly on my Windows 10 64bits. Hope you find a solution

Comment: Is L really your username? Im asking because sometimes meteor builds throw strange errors when directory structure goes too long. Are you able to create app to c temp?

Comment: Don't use meteor in an administrator prompt. It's likely to give you hard to diagnose issues like this